# how to make jtextfield only accept characters in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I have done a  sample project in netbeans of registration. In the jtextfield1 is the user id and Jtextfiled7 is  country, Both  must in characters not in numeric or not allowed spaces and special characters.how it is possible?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662651/how-to-implement-in-java-jtextfield-class-to-allow-entering-only-digits)'s answers will show you the right approach, although you'll need to modify it (since it's doing basically the opposite of what you want).

Comment: Have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Comment: You could also have a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Comment: I was making a small swing application that needed to validate a `JTextField`s input a couple of weeks ago. I found the question linked in the first comment and implemented the code and it worked but I wanted to do more than what it offered, so another search lead me to MadProgrammer's Validating Input link and it offered everything I wanted. I'd suggest implementing the former for a quick solution and the ladder for an in-depth solution.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371647/can-not-write-editable-jcombobox/34372342#34372342) with a document filter I gave today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vivek ,

I have the answer for this question you asked. please do as per following instructions.

In Netbeans  right click on JTextfield and select the events>>key>>key typed and enter the following code between the codes. the following is the code for it for only accept characters

```
enter code here
char c=evt.getKeyChar();

    if(!(Character.isAlphabetic(c) ||  (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE)||  c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE ))
        evt.consume();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JFormattedTextField or you can code inside the JTextField's KeyTyped event

```
jTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

         if(!(Character.isLetter(evt.getKeyChar()))){
                evt.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, no, no. It is never appropriate to use a KeyListener with a text component, instead, use a DocumentFilter, it's what's it designed for

Answer (score 1):

For real time validation, use a `DocumentFilter`, see and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details.

Have a look at:

- [JTextField limiting character amount input and accepting numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793030/jtextfield-limiting-character-amount-input-and-accepting-numeric-only/12793126#12793126)
- [How to set DocumentFilter with input length and range? e.g. 1-3 or 10-80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166921/how-to-set-documentfilter-with-input-length-and-range-e-g-1-3-or-10-80/15168429#15168429)

for more examples.

For post validation, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details