# How can I modify my code to only accept a certain data type?

Tags: java

What can I do to modify this, is there any java function for that? 
What needs to be done so that it only accepts characters and returns an error message for other data types?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class problem5
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a letter from the alphabet: ");
        char letter = in.next(".").charAt(0);
        char vowels[] = {'A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u'};
        int vowelcount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          if (vowels[i] == letter)
          {
            vowelcount++;
          }
        }
        if (vowelcount > 0)
        {
          System.out.println("You entered a vowel.");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("You entered a consonant.");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Well, everything is character in a `String`. You want to check if you only get alphabetic character maybe ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner

Comment: If I need to reject two character strings and above; and numbers what should I add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make jtextfield only accept characters in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377607/how-to-make-jtextfield-only-accept-characters-in-netbeans)

Comment: "_I need to reject two character strings and above_" You mean you have a list of `rejectedChar` ? Or you are rejecting `String` that have more than 1 character ? (String.length > 1)

Comment: no I need to reject input that has more than 1 char

Comment: Check the length of the String ... ?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to reject input that has more than 1 char – Nico Dela Cruz

You just need to check the length of your input

```
String input = in.next(".");
if(input.length == 1){
    char letter = input.charAt(0);
    ...
}
```

Add an `else` if you want to add an error message of some sort.

To check the input to only accept `letter`, you have [`Character.isLetter(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) to check every "letter" in UNICODE for you.

If you want to only accept a range of `a-z` and/or `A-Z`, you can do it yourself with an if condition or using regex.

Comment: thanks! but how do I reject numbers/integers as inputs?

Comment: @NicoDelaCruz You just said you want to reject `String` too long .... for the rest of the reject, check the duplicates proposed or the answer above. This is a recurrent question

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your loop in a statement such as:

```
if (Character.isLetter(letter)){
```

and put and `else` clause at the end for your error

Edit:

OP has changed their question slightly, so you can either:

-Accept only the first character entered:

```
char letter = in.next().trim().charAt(0);
```

-Or as AxelH said above, only proceed if user enters one char:

```
if(input.length == 1){
    char letter = input.charAt(0);
```